# why isn't monitor listed under /dev in linux?

Tags: linux, devices, monitors

If /dev is suppose to list all the devices that is connected, like usb, hdd, webcam, how come on my ubuntu 15 VM I don't see a monitor? I am running the desktop edition so there should be a monitor.

Or maybe it is named something different?

Comment: May be the OS does not communicate with the monitor?

Comment: Some physical devices need an interface in the filesystem, others don't.  Network cards don't have corresponding entries in `/dev` either.

Comment: how could the OS not communicate with the monitor? how else does it display anything?

Comment: Mostly, the OS communicates with the graphics card, and the graphics card communicates with the monitor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Device files on Unix systems in general are just one way for user programs to access device drivers; there isn't a one-to-one mapping from devices files to physical hardware, and not all hardware has a device file (or even a device driver). The kernel itself doesn't use device files to interact with hardware.

As pointed out by [lcd047](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/111878/lcd047), network cards don't have device files at all. Programs interact with the network using APIs, *e.g.* the [BSD socket API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets); even `ethtool` uses a socket and [`ioctl()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl) to manipulate the network interface.

So when determining whether your monitor has a device file, it's useful to think of the ways programs interact with it. There aren't many tools which interact directly with a monitor... Programs display information on a monitor *via* a graphics card, and that does have device files: `/dev/dri/*`, `/dev/fb*` etc. But that's not the monitor. The only programs I know of which interact with a monitor directly are backlight control programs and `ddccontrol`; the former generally use ACPI or laptop-specific devices (so the monitor's backlight is just a part of the system's power-usage model), and `ddccontrol` uses the [I²C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) bus whose devices appear as `/dev/i2c-*` once the `i2c-dev` module is loaded.